# How to implement lazy loading in listview wpf VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm newbie, I've a XAML file and code behind's, its load all data but I will lazy loading. I binding data in listview. I tried searching but did not produce the expected results, so there is no way that can be done.

**code behind**:

```
 Public Sub MappingThumbnailSearchResult(thumbSearchResult As VI_ThumbnailSearchResultResponse, token As CancellationToken, ByRef dataDic As Dictionary(Of String, ObservableCollection(Of Object)))
        Dim data As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)
        Try
            If thumbSearchResult.result_body Is Nothing OrElse thumbSearchResult.result_body.search_result Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            For Each item In thumbSearchResult.result_body.search_result
                Try
                    If token.IsCancellationRequested Then Exit Sub

                    Dim thumbnailKey As String = ""
                    If Not item.thumbnail_key.Contains("\\") Then
                        thumbnailKey = item.thumbnail_key.ToString().Replace("\", "\\")
                    Else
                        thumbnailKey = item.thumbnail_key
                    End If

                    Dim imageResult = RequestAPI.GetInstance.GetThumbnailBase64(New VI_ThumbnailRequest With {.ThumbnailKey = thumbnailKey})
                    Dim hasThumb As Boolean = False
                    If imageResult IsNot Nothing Then
                        If imageResult.result_body.thumbnail IsNot Nothing Then
                            hasThumb = True
                            Dim base64Str As String = imageResult.result_body.thumbnail
                            item.thumbnail_base64 = imageResult.result_body.thumbnail
                            item.thumbnail_bitmap = BaseViewModel.BitmapFromSource(BaseViewModel.Base64ToImage(base64Str))
                        End If
                    End If

                    If Not hasThumb Then
                        'default image if have error when get thumbnail image
                        If item.system_type.Equals(EnumType.SystemType.face.ToString()) Then
                            item.thumbnail_base64 = BaseViewModel.ConvertBitmapToBase64(My.Resources.gender_unknown_2)
                            item.thumbnail_bitmap = My.Resources.gender_unknown_2
                        ElseIf item.system_type.Equals(EnumType.SystemType.people.ToString()) Then
                            item.thumbnail_base64 = BaseViewModel.ConvertBitmapToBase64(My.Resources.People)
                            item.thumbnail_bitmap = My.Resources.People
                        End If
                    End If

                    Dim tmpDate As DateTime
                    Dim shotDate As Date
                    If DateTime.TryParseExact(item.shot_date_time, RESPONSE_DATE_FORMAT2, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, tmpDate) Then
                        shotDate = tmpDate
                    Else
                        shotDate = DateTime.Now
                    End If

                    Dim dateKey As String = shotDate.ToString(PRIVATE_DATE_FORMAT)
                    If Not dataDic.ContainsKey(dateKey) Then
                        Dim thumbList = New ObservableCollection(Of Object)
                        Dim objThumb As Object = MappingVIThumbnailFromResponse(item, shotDate)
                        thumbList.Add(objThumb)
                        dataDic.Add(dateKey, thumbList)
                    Else
                        Dim objThumb As Object = MappingVIThumbnailFromResponse(item, shotDate)
                        dataDic.Item(dateKey).Add(objThumb)
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Dim b As Integer = 0
                End Try
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim c As Integer = 0
        End Try
    End Sub
```

After, I binding data as below

```
Dim result As ObservableCollection(Of ListViewThumbnailViewModel) = New ObservableCollection(Of ListViewThumbnailViewModel)
            If dataDic.Count > 0 Then
                If token.IsCancellationRequested Then Return data
                For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, ObservableCollection(Of Object)) In dataDic
                    Dim _date As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pair.Key, PRIVATE_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    result.Add(New ListViewThumbnailViewModel() With {.DateItem = _date, .ListThumbnail = pair.Value})
                    _viewModel.ResultSearch.TotalData += pair.Value.Count
                Next

                _viewModel.ResultSearch.ListResult = result
                _viewModel.ResultSearch.ListResultActual = result
                _viewModel.ResultSearch.PageSize = PageHelper.GetPageSizeWithZoom(_viewModel.ResultSearch.ZoomImage * 10, _viewModel.ResultSearch.PageSizeStart, _viewModel.ResultSearch.NumberChange)
                _viewModel.ResultSearch.PageCurrent = 0
                _viewModel.ResultSearch.TotalPage = PageHelper.GetTotalPageByPageSize(result.Count, _viewModel.ResultSearch.PageSize)
            Else
                _viewModel.ResultSearch.ListResult = Nothing
                _viewModel.ResultSearch.ListResultActual = Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New AIMatchingException(ex)
        End Try
        Return data
```

What should I do? please help me, thanks!!!